# How to force UIView (mapView) to take up the entire screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

To set a UIView to take up the entire screen, is this correct?

```
self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Or should I be using the self.view.bounds...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of frame and bounds for view as frame and bounds are same for it. But when you work with subviews then use bounds because frame and bounds need not be the same. For subview they are same only when your subview's size is same as its superview.